# Around 1640s, at what time did people eat Christmas dinner?

Tags: technology, christianity, 17th-century, christmas

To my knowledge, in the past, people used to go to bed earlier; usually at sunset.

My question is, around 1640s, when candles were used to light the interiors of buildings, at what time of day did Catholics at home eat Christmas dinner in Holy Roman Empire (particularly in Bohemia)? During daylight or after dark?

Comment: Are you assuming the answer to be the same across all of Christendom, or do you have a specific region or culture in mind? And what of the many Christians who did not celebrate Christmas, but would eat dinner on Christmas day as they would on any other day—do you count those meals as "Christmas dinners"?

Comment: ..and there were Christian cultures that celebrated Christmas over a period of [twelve days](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Days_of_Christmas), so they didn't have a single Christmas dinner.

Comment: @Steve Bird: I edit the question to make it more to the point

Comment: "To my knowledge, people of the past used to go to bed earlier; usually at the sunset." [Probably not](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biphasic_and_polyphasic_sleep#Interrupted_sleep). Or at least not in any way that can be usefully generalised. Which makes sense when most people only need 8 hours' sleep - the whole night is too much.

Comment: Even today my family eats Christmas dinner at a different hour than my professional historian girlfriend's family does.  I question the assumption that there is a "standard" or "conventional" time - practice probably varies as much between families as between era or culture.

Comment: Always an hour later than expected, because the dang roast isn't done.

Comment: When I was growing up Sunday and Christmas "Dinner" would be about 2pm - but then, we'd call our regular evening meal "tea", taken about 6ish.

Comment: The first thing to bear in mind is that "Christmas" as we understand it today only really began in the nineteenth-century - at least that is certainly the case in Britain. Another is that in some places such as the UK, in late December "sunset" is at about 3.30pm. In some parts of Scandinavia there is no daylight at all.

Answer (score 4):

**Around 1640s, at what time did people eat Christmas dinner?**

It is quite common knowledge the in times prior to modern conveniences such as electricity and natural gas for cooking the main meal would be anytime around noon to mid-afternoon.

Seeing that your question deals specificity with Christmas, it would probably be more around 12:00 PM or even a little earlier, depending on when the Church Faithful got home from the church services.

Please bare in mind that cities such as Paris or one’s further north start getting dark around 4:30 PM.

This practice of eating towards the midday is is done traditionally in some areas in Europe, notably in Benedictine Monasteries.

Most people ate two meals a day, dinner at midday, and supper, in the evening. Breakfast, as a separate meal, was a later concept. Those who worked in the fields either took food with them or someone brought it out to them when it was ready. The word lunch meant snack—something that could be eaten while walking or working—for quick energy. Fresh or dried fruit, perhaps with a piece of cheese, was a common lunch. - [How Dining in the Middle Ages Differs From Now](https://stores.renstore.com/history-and-traditions/how-dining-in-the-middle-ages-differs-from-now)

Supper in *Olden Days* meant something generally different than in modern days: supper meant something more along the line of a very little meal or even a snack with some soup and served in the evening.

Exception to the rule are historically known, but generally amongst the very wealthy who could afford to light up ballrooms with candlelight.

> [**Supper**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supper) was originally a secondary lighter evening meal. The main meal of the day, called dinner, used to be served closer to what is known as lunchtime, around the middle of the day, but crept later over the centuries, mostly over the course of the 19th century. When dinner was still at the early time, eating a lighter supper in the evening was very common; it was not always the last meal of the day, as there might be a tea later. Reflecting the typical custom of 17th century elites, Louis XIV dined at noon, with a supper at 10 PM. Even when dinner was in the early evening, supper was served at, or on return from, a ball, and might be after other evening excursions. At an English ball in 1791, supper was served to 140 guests at 1:00 AM. They would all have had dinner at home many hours earlier, before coming out. Other, grander, balls served supper even later, up to 3:30 AM, at a London ball given in 1811 by the Duchess of Bedford.
>
> **Etymology**
>
> The term is derived from the French souper, which is used for this meal in Canadian French, Swiss French, and in Belgian French. It is related to soup. It is also related to the Scandinavian words for soup, soppa or suppe and the German word for soup, Suppe. The Oxford English Dictionary, however, suggests that the root, sup, remains obscure in origin.

Charles Dickens’ [***A Christmas Carol***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Carol) known the world over is surprisingly accurate in many historical facts around the subject matter of food, meals and drinks. This novel although published in 1843 holds to the [basic urban living](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=OhF_UJkHFh8) of the 17th century: no central heating or [electric lightbulbs](https://www.bulbs.com/learning/history.aspx)!

> [image]
>
> Alcohol flows freely in the writing of Charles Dickens. Though drinking was largely frowned upon in Victorian society, Dickens enjoyed drinking in moderation, and felt that nobody should begrudge the citizens of England this simple, age-old pleasure. Dickens was known to have a fondness for sweet alcoholic punches, which were quite popular at the time. One such drink, a mulled wine punch known as a **Smoking Bishop**, is mentioned in his timeless holiday classic, A Christmas Carol.
>
> “A merry Christmas, Bob!” said Scrooge, with an earnestness that could not be mistaken, as he clapped him on the back. “A merrier Christmas, Bob, my good fellow, than I have given you, for many a year! I’ll raise your salary, and endeavour to assist your struggling family, and we will discuss your affairs this very afternoon, over a Christmas bowl of **smoking bishop**, Bob!”
>
> Among the ‘***Oxford night-caps***’ bishop appears to be one of the oldest winter beverages on record, and to this very day is preferred to every other, not only by the youthful votary of Bacchus, at his evening revelry, but also by the grave Don by way of a nightcap. It is not improbable that this celebrated drink, equally known to our continental neighbours under the somewhat similar name of bischof, derived its name from the circumstance of ancient dignitaries of the church, when they honoured the university with a visit, being regaled with spiced wine. -[Drinking with Charles Dickens – the smoking bishop](https://toriavey.com/toris-kitchen/drinking-with-charles-dickens-the-smoking-bishop/)

Comment: Why "surprisingly" accurate?  Wasn't he writing about his contemporary time?

Comment: What makes you think that Dickens holds to the "basic urban living of the 17th century"? Highly unlikely, I'd say. For one thing there was not much "urban living" to speak of before the Industrial Revolution. (And it would be quite ridiculous to imagine the Cratchits would have had central heating or electic light in 1843 anyway) Nonetheless the modern British Christmas is widely recognised as originating during Victoria's reign.  The names given to the various meals of the day and how they have changed across time and social classes has been widely discussed on English Language Users site.

Comment: @WS2 "For one thing there was not much "urban living" to speak of before the Industrial Revolution" how exactly do you support this? I did think that Rome, Athens, Carthage, London etc all existed as places before the industrial revolution and people rich and poor did live quite differently there than they did out in the countryside

Comment: @bigbadmouse Yes, I will concede that London was already an urban area with a population of about 250,000., out of a total national population for England of about 4.5 million.  But there were no other cities at all much greater than one-tenth the size of London.

Comment: Apart from Bristol, Portsmouth, Liverpool etc all had populations greater than 25000 people

Comment: @bigbadmouse I am unclear of what you are saying. But in the 17th century the largest city, in England, outside of London, was Norwich, perhaps closely followed by Bristol. Even in the late-18th century the population of Norwich was only about 40,000. The reason it was so relatively large was because of its wool-weaving industry. Elsewhere weaving, and other proto-industries, mining etc were conducted in villages, sometimes loosely grouped geographically - such as woolens in West Yorkshire. Urban growth of ports and manufacturing had only just begun in the late 18th century.